# Notice: Undefined index: updat in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\location_master.php on line 14

Tags: php

```php
<?php
    require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php'));
    $db = new Connect;
    $no_of_rides = 0;
    $user = ("SELECT * FROM cab_booking_requests");
    $result = $db->query($user);

    echo '<table>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>E mail</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>check</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Button</th>
      </tr>';

    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
        require_once 'location_master.php';
        while($info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $bookingid = $info["bookingid"];
            $status = $info["status"];
            $reason = $info["reason"];
            $customer_name = $info["customer_name"];

            echo "<tr><td></td><td>".$status."</td><td>".$reason."</td><td>".$customer_name.'</td><td><div class="body">
          <div class="input-emails">
          <form method="POST" action="location_master.php">
            <select class="combo" id="combobox" name="select" >
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="deactive">DeActive</option>
              
              
            </select>
          </td><td><input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="check" value="false">
          </td><td><input type="text" name="updat"  value="'.$bookingid.'" disabled>
          </td><td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
          </td></div></tr></form>';
        }

        echo '</table></div>';
    }
```

This error is really killing me.
I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

- `if (isset($_POST['update']) && isset($_POST['check']) && isset($_POST['select']) && isset($_POST['updat']))`
- `if (isset($_POST['update'], $_POST['check'],$_POST['select'],$_POST['updat'])){`

> Notice: Undefined index: updat in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\location_master.php on line 14

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" class="js">
    <?php
        require_once('sidebar.php');
    ?>

    <div>
    <?php
        require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php'));
        require_once('830.php');
        
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $true = $_POST['check'];
            $satus = $_POST['select'];
            $i = $_POST['updat'];
            echo $satus;
            
            $db = new Connect;
            $user = ("SELECT * FROM cab_booking_requests");
            $result = $db->query($user);
            $info = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $hash = $satus;
            $stu = $true;
            
            $upd = $db->prepare("UPDATE cab_booking_requests SET telecall_status =:hash, telecaller_check=:st WHERE bookingid=:ex_user");
            $upd -> execute(array(
                'hash' => $hash,
                'st' => $stu,
                'ex_user' => $i
            ));
            //$db-> query("INSERT INTO cab_booking_requests (telecall_status,telecaller_check) VALUES ('$satus','$true')") or die($mysqli->error);
        }else{
            echo "somehing went wrong";
        }
    ?> 
    </div>

    <?php
        require_once('footer.php');
    ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Your field is `disabled` therefor it wont be submitted. You can use `readonly` instead

Comment: I tryed  readonly   it's not work sir

Comment: $true = $_POST['check'];
       $satus = $_POST['select'];   these two work perfectly then why  $i = $_POST['updat'];  it's not work...

Comment: How about using correct typo? `update`

Comment: no it is not the answer.

Comment: sir, the answer mainly focused on Undefined variable..

Answer (score 0):

updat field is disabled is your submission, hence it is not submitted and therefore your submission script could not receive it so it says undefined index. If you want that field to be disabled so that user cant change it, make it readonly not disabled.

Comment: i changed readonly then it is notwork

Answer (score 0):

Write **print_r($_POST)** in the code and check all the post data that is coming from the client side i.e browser check weather index **updat** is available or not

**Reason if index is not available**

1. The field is disabled.
2. Your are using wrong selector in JavaScript for fetching variable.
3. Missing "." in case of class name or "#" in case of ID (In Case of jQuery).
4. The field display property is none.
5. If the value is coming from radio button and none of the radio is checked.

Please provide the client side scripting also if the answer won't provide any solution

Comment: Javascript has nothing to due with OP's answer. Also hidding an input doesn't prevent the input's value being passed to the backed - [demo](https://www.darkbee.be/stack/hidden.php)

Comment: yes the data is not coming

Comment: index updat is not  available ///Array ( [select] => deactive [check] => false [update] => Update )